# How to change migration generator EF CORE 2.x?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I need to add some functionality in migration generator and automatically add InsertData in migration.

I have already created custom CSharpMigrationsGenerator, but I don't know how and where to register it.

```
public class CustomCSharpMigrationCodeGenerator : CSharpMigrationsGenerator
    {
        public override string GenerateMigration(string migrationNamespace, 
            string migrationName, 
            IReadOnlyList<MigrationOperation> upOperations, 
            IReadOnlyList<MigrationOperation> downOperations)
        {
            throw new Exception("Hello world");
            return base.GenerateMigration(migrationNamespace, migrationName, upOperations, downOperations);
        }

        public CustomCSharpMigrationCodeGenerator(MigrationsCodeGeneratorDependencies dependencies, 
            CSharpMigrationsGeneratorDependencies csharpDependencies) : base(dependencies, csharpDependencies)
        {
            throw new Exception("Hello world");
        }
    }
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
public class MyDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<CSharpMigrationsGenerator, CustomCSharpMigrationCodeGenerator>();
    }
}
```

Where do I need to register it? Or do I use wrong class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Just the service this class implements (and you need to replace) is [IMigrationsCodeGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.design.imigrationscodegenerator?view=efcore-2.1):

```
public class MyDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMigrationsCodeGenerator, CustomCSharpMigrationCodeGenerator>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice it( 4 hours are lost